# Recommended Rails gem for user access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, hipaa

Looking for a gem to "log user access" for HIPAA (and other) compliance. I guess this means tracking logins, logouts, and everything that the user does in between.

Are there any recommended gems to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails already does logging, so the best solution was to add the following to the existing logs:

1. Logins
2. Logouts
3. Currently logged in user to existing log entries. Rails already logging controller actions and parameters.

Although the log is not the easiest data to analyze, there are no requirements about about it so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Devise tracks logins and IP by default. As far as recording "everything" the user does. You will have to code some of this on your own methinks.